# Почему в Rust нет аналога Vec::with_capacity() такого как Vec::with_len()

Tags: vector, rust

Я знаю что можно написать так:

```
let v = Vec::with_capacity(n);
unsafe { v.set_len(n); }
```

Но почему в Rust нет возможности создать вектор данной длины не заполняя его (что не логично по производительности) или не прибегая к `unsafe` ?

Comment: Если вектор не заполнять, значит в нём будет находиться мусор, который раньше лежал в его памяти. А работать с мусором — естественно небезопасно

Comment: ясно, вполне похоже на ответ

Comment: дык потому что rust заботится о твоём благополучии и принципиально не позволяет создавать неинициализированные значения... без `unsafe`... а эффект на производительности в большинстве случаев должен нивелироваться оптимизатором...

Comment: можно поподробнее про оптимизатор?

Comment: @andreymal напишите ответ, закрою вопрос

Comment: @MeowningMaster, что-то конкретное не скажу и не смогу подкрепить свои слова исследованием, но вполне ожидается, что банальная серия `push`'ев  в цикле должны быть эквивалентна одному изменению длины и серии присваиваний...

Comment: да, но так в 2 раза больше присваиваний

Comment: @MeowningMaster, почему? если ты про изменение размера вектора, то я как раз и полагаю, что оптимизатор должен быть достаточно умён, чтобы вынести его за цикл...

Comment: не думаю что он выносит его за цикл, я думаю что он увеличивает capacity в 1.5-2 раза каждый раз когда заканчиваеться зарезервированая память (по крайней мере в c++ так реализовано)

Comment: и мне не push нужен а доступ по индексу

Comment: @MeowningMaster, мда... посмотрел — про оптимизацию я был не прав... не говоря о том, что даже при обычной записи он runtime'овые проверки на переполнения вставляет для каждого доступа к элементу вектора...

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понял из исходников - `Vec::with_capacity` как раз ничего не заполняет, а по описанию, делает именно то, о чем вы пишете - создает вектор заданной длины без заполнения. Естественно, при этом Rust защищает вас от доступа к мусорным значениям через *length* равным 0 (см [Capacity and reallocation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#capacity-and-reallocation)).

Все это сделано как раз для случаев когда вам нужна производительность - после вызова `Vec::with_capacity` `vec.push` не будет делать реалокацию. В идеале, при правильном переданном значении в `Vec::with_capacity` и дальнейшем заполнении массива значениями в цикле, у вас не будет ни одной реалокации массива и присваивание значения будет только один раз.

Comment: проблема в том, что, во-первых, на каждой итерации цикла `rust` всё равно будет дёргать `veс.length`, прибавляя каждый раз единичку и, что ещё хуже, он будет проверять, не превысился ли объём также при каждом `push`'е, а, во-вторых, ОП хочет заполнять вектор в произвольном порядке... например, инвертировать подстановку... так что `unsafe` тут, похоже, единственный и правильный выбор...

Comment: @Fat-Zer прибавлять `veс.length` на каждой итерации практически ничего не будет стоить, т.к. с большой долей вероятности это значение будет лежать в регистре и инкрементация, которая будет выполнена в несколько раз быстрее чтения/записи из памяти/кеша, может быть выполнена процессором одновременно с другими операциями.

Для заполнения массива в произвольном порядке я бы постарался не использовать `unsafe` и подвергать риску свои ноги, а постарался бы вызывать  `vec.push` подставляя  значения таким образом, чтобы в итоге получился массив с нужным порядком.

Comment: нет, он будет сохранять в память на каждой итерации... я тоже думал, что оптимизатор с этим может что-то сделать, пока не проверил... код генерируемый rust'ом при наивном использовании довольно ужасен (немного хуже плюсов) и «Performance» без unsafe'а из своих «Choose 3» он ни как не получит... печально, но факт...

Comment: насколько я знаю, по крайней мере в c++ так, при достижении лимита длины вектора его длина увеличиваеться в 1.5-2 раза и аллоцируеться соответствующее количество памяти. так что `veс.length` изменяеться далеко не при каждом добавлении